# grunt cli option always undefined

Tags: gruntjs, command-line-interface

I am attempting to use the Grunt cli with options, with no luck.

Just to test I am doing something like:

```
var baseRoute = grunt.option('baseRoute');

grunt.registerTask('testing', function (){
  console.log(grunt.option('baseRoute'));
  console.log(baseRoute);
});
```

I end up with 'undefined'

If I set a default, such as:

```
var baseRoute = grunt.option('baseRoute') || '/';

grunt.registerTask('testing', function (){
  console.log(grunt.option('baseRoute'));
  console.log(baseRoute);
});
```

I always end up with /, no matter what value I pass in.

I am specifying the option like so:

```
grunt --baseRoute=admin testing
```

or

```
grunt testing --baseRoute=admin
```

Edited:

Version: `grunt-cli v0.1.13` and `grunt v0.4.2`

The Gruntfile is quite large so, I may remove some before posting it.

Comment: could you share the whole Gruntfile.js, I've tried it and it works for me. Also what version of grunt are you using? ```grunt --version``` outputs ```grunt-cli v0.1.11``` and ```grunt v0.4.4```

Answer (score 0):

I had `grunt.option.init({})` in my Gruntfile. When I took it out, the grunt option worked.

After figuring out the problem, I found this: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1023